# No html5 option in netflix

Tags: netflix

I have recently signed up with netflix and have followed procedures in updating chrome and set up user agent switcher but when I try to change playback settings in netflix to html5 the setting is not available.

Comment: Could you describe how "the setting is not available"? Does it give you any errors?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Chrome browser supports Netflix natively now, no need to do anything to it.